# how to make my bot mention the person who gave that bot command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making a discord bot, and I want to do this: someone type `-ping` and the bot responds with `@theuserwhotyped-ping`.

I have no errors, I just don't know how to code it, and I don't find any solution on the Internet.

Here is the code I made:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = "-";

client.on("message", message=>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;


const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command === "ping"){
    message.channel.send("@{user}); //this is the line which dont work
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `message.reply`:

```js
message.reply('typed ping');
```

It sends a reply, like `@peter, typed ping`.

Or use the `message.author`:

```js
message.channel.send(`${message.author} typed ping`);
```

It sends a message like `@peter typed ping`.

Comment: I would not recommend using `Message#reply` as the next major version of DJS (v13) will replace the method to function as an inline reply.