# discord.js getting the bot to execute "@(person who typed the command)"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am new to discord.js and wanted to make the bot to reply to the person who sent the command. For example:

```
Person1: !hello
Bot: Hello, @Person1
```

Usually, I would create my commands like this:

**main/index.js**

```
if(command === 'cmd'){
        client.commands.get('cmd').execute(message, args);
```

**cmd.js**

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'cmd',
    description: 'example command',
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('this is a command');
    }
}
```

If it's possible to do it in this format, it would be really helpful. Again, apologies for my lack of understanding this is still very new to me. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make my bot mention the person who gave that bot command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091776/how-to-make-my-bot-mention-the-person-who-gave-that-bot-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the [`message.author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) to mention the author of the message like this:

```js
execute(message, args) {
  message.channel.send(`Hello, ${message.author}!`);
}
```

[image]